# Is there any Android application that can manipulate the http response?

Tags: android, function-hooking, https-protocol

Is there any android app to manipulate http response body without vpn?

*for example:*

**from**

```
"0|{random_string}|Wrong"
```

**Becomes**

```
"1|{random_string}|True"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have only the phone (no external PC or server) and a non-rooted Android phone then VPN is the only way for an app to get access to the network traffic. With an external server you could set it up as proxy and configure your phone accordingly. And on a rooted device there are possibilities to get access to the network traffix without VPN (or even manipulate the data in the app before sending/receiving it).

Comment: What can I do if the phone is rooted? @Robert

Comment: You have full access to iptables and can thus redirect IP or TCP streams.